# Unable to get data on weekly basis in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am trying to get data from a table on Weekly basis, like I want to get total number of records registered on Monday, Tuesday an so on. I am able to create a script in MySQL and it works fine, but when I try to do the same in Laravel then it throws an error:

**MySQL query (works fine):**

```
SELECT HOUR(`created_on`) AS Hour, COUNT(*) AS calls
FROM  `buy_credits_requests`
GROUP BY HOUR(`created_on`)
```

**Laravel query (doesn't work)**

```
$credits = \DB::table('buy_credits_requests')->where('status', '=', 1)->groupBy('Hour', 'ASC')
->get(['HOUR(created_on) AS Hour', 'COUNT(*) AS calls', 'state']);
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$credits = \DB::table('buy_credits_requests')->select(DB::raw('HOUR(created_on) AS Hour'),DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS calls'))->where('status', 1)->groupBy('Hour')
->get();
```

You had problem in your syntax,
Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this, it gives this error: Unknown column 'HOUR(created_on)'

Comment: Check now made changes

Comment: there is an extra ) at the end of the query, rest is fine, thanks for your help, i am going to accept this as answer :)